# jTable grid lines for selected rows

Tags: java, jtable

I have a jTable set so that it is read only, and selection is done by single row only.

However, when the user selects a row and the row is painted, the jTable's vertical grid lines between columns are removed, causing a single horizontal block of colour, instead of blocks of colour in each cell.

How can I get the selected row to show the vertical lines between each cell in adjacent columns?

Comment: Here's a link to an image showing what I mean, with the missing line circled: http://www.algaia.co.uk/grid.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ensured that `myTable.setShowGrid(true)`,  `myTable.setShowVerticalLines(true)` have been called? What's your grid colour, and could it be the same as the selection background colour?

**Update:** I used the following simple [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) script to create a read-only table:

```
from javax.swing import *
from java.awt import *
from javax.swing.table import DefaultTableModel, DefaultTableCellRenderer

class MyTableModel(DefaultTableModel):
    def isCellEditable(self, row, col):
        return False

class UnfocusableRenderer(DefaultTableCellRenderer):
    def getTableCellRendererComponent(self, table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col):
        return DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(self, table, value, isSelected, False, row, col)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame = JFrame("Read-only JTable")
    frame.setSize(400, 150)
    frame.setLayout(BorderLayout())
    tableData = [
      ['', ''],
      ['', ''],
    ]
    colNames = ('Title 1','Title 2')
    dataModel = MyTableModel(tableData, colNames)
    table = JTable(dataModel)
    r = UnfocusableRenderer()
    for colindex in (0, 1):
        tc = table.columnModel.getColumn(colindex)
        tc.cellRenderer = r

    scrollPane = JScrollPane()
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(Dimension(370,106))
    scrollPane.getViewport().setView(table)

    panel = JPanel()
    panel.add(scrollPane)
    panel.background = Color.blue.darker()

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER)
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    frame.setVisible(True)
```

This is the screenshot when I select a row:

[image]

As this is showing the gridlines, could it be something to do with your renderers, colours or resources?

Comment: Yes, setShowgrid & setShowVerticalLines are both true. Without those, I wouldn't be seeing any of the vertical lines between the columns at all.

It is just the row that is selected that doesn't draw these vertical lines.

The grid I have is white background, black lines (inverted for the header row), with the highlight row coloured orange. (shown here: http://www.algaia.co.uk/grid.jpg)

I've circled where I was expecting a vertical line...

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement your own cellrenderer ?

If you did make sure you still set a border in your

```
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(...)
```

method